# How to get users with 3 or more consecutive weeks in order using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a user table like this,

```
    USERID  Week_Number  Year
0       fb          5.0  2021
1  twitter          1.0  2021
2  twitter          2.0  2021
3  twitter          3.0  2021
4  twitter          1.0  2022
5  twitter          2.0  2022
6  twitter          3.0  2022
7  twitter         15.0  2022
8  twitter          NaN   NaN
9    human         21.0  2022
```

I want to find the users who login >= 3 consecutive weeks in the same year. The week numbers will be unique for each year. For example, in the above table we can see that user twitter is logged in week_no: 1, 2, 3 in the same year 2022 thereby satisfying the condition that I am looking for.

The output I am looking for,

```
USERID        Year
twitter       2021
twitter       2022
```

You can create the sample table using,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"USERID": ["fb", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "twitter", "human"],
                     "Week_Number": [5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 15, np.nan, 21],
                     "Year": ["2021", "2021","2021","2021", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", np.nan, "2022"]})
```

Can someone help me achieve this required output? I have tried few things but not able to arrive at proper output.

```
for ix, group in data.groupby([data.USERID, data.Year]):
    group = group.sort_values("Week_Number")
    group["Diff"] = (group.Week_Number - group.Week_Number.shift(1)).fillna(1)
    break
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not interested in the details of when the run of at least three weeks occurred (start or end), but only the tuples `(user, year)` where the user had at least three consecutive weeks of usage, then it is quite simple:

```py
def min_consecutive(w, minimum_run=3):
    dy = w.diff() != 1
    runlen = dy.groupby(dy.cumsum()).size()
    return (runlen >= minimum_run).any()

s = (
    data
    .sort_values('Week_Number')
    .groupby(['USERID', 'Year'])['Week_Number']
    .apply(min_consecutive)
)
>>> s[s]
USERID   Year
twitter  2021    True
         2022    True
Name: Week_Number, dtype: bool
```

#### Explanation

We consider each group `(user, year)`. In that group, we observe an (ordered, without repeats) series of week numerals. This could be e.g. `[1,2,3,12,13,18,19,20,21]` (a run of 3, a run of 2, and a run of 4). The Series `dy` shows where there were gaps in the run (e.g. for the hypothetical value above: `[T,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F]`). We use the `.cumsum()` of that to make groups that are each a consecutive run, e.g. `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]`. We take the `size` of each group (e.g. `[3,2,4]`), and return `True` iff any of those is at least `minimum_run` long.

#### Addendum: locate the weeks that meet the criteria

Here are some ideas, depending on how you'd like your output.

```py
df = data.dropna().sort_values(['USERID', 'Year', 'Week_Number'])
df = df.assign(rungrp=(df.groupby(['USERID', 'Year'])['Week_Number'].diff() != 1).cumsum())
df = df.loc[df.groupby('rungrp')['rungrp'].transform('count') >= 3]
>>> df
    USERID  Week_Number  Year  rungrp
1  twitter          1.0  2021       3
2  twitter          2.0  2021       3
3  twitter          3.0  2021       3
4  twitter          1.0  2022       4
5  twitter          2.0  2022       4
6  twitter          3.0  2022       4
```

All the weeks that are part of a run of at least 3.

Grouping to find week min and max of each run:

```py
>>> df.groupby(['USERID', 'Year', 'rungrp'])['Week_Number'].agg([min, max])
                     min  max
USERID  Year rungrp          
twitter 2021 3       1.0  3.0
        2022 4       1.0  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it's a last minute request but it is possible to fetch the "Week_Number" as tuple or list rather than True of False in the output? For example in the case of twitter - 2022 it's (1, 2, 3). It would definitely provide more info for me to extend this work I am doing.

Comment: Yes, of course, I was kind of expecting that follow up... The question is: what is the desired output? For example, in the case where there are several satisfactory runs for a given `(user, year)`, say for example: `[1,2,3,4, 8,9, 30,31,32]`?

Comment: Ok, I put a couple of ideas for you in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping you can create a column which will show whether a user in a year has had a consecutive increase, and then check if that column sums to more than 3 per user in a year:

```
data.sort_values(by=['USERID','Year','Week_Number'],ascending=True,inplace=True)

data.assign(
    grouped_increase = data.groupby([data.USERID, data.Year])["Week_Number"]
    .diff()
    .gt(0)
    .astype(int)
).groupby([data.USERID, data.Year])["grouped_increase"].sum().reset_index().query(
    "grouped_increase >= 3"
).drop(
    "grouped_increase", axis=1
)
```

---

```
    USERID  Year
3  twitter  2022
```

Based on your comment, using this `DF`:

```
     USERID  Week_Number    Year
8        fb          2.0  2021.0
9        fb          3.0  2021.0
10       fb          4.0  2021.0
0        fb          5.0  2021.0
11       fb          2.0  2022.0
12       fb          3.0  2022.0
13       fb          4.0  2022.0
14       fb          5.0  2022.0
7     human         21.0  2022.0
1   twitter          1.0  2021.0
2   twitter          1.0  2022.0
3   twitter          2.0  2022.0
4   twitter          3.0  2022.0
5   twitter         15.0  2022.0
6   twitter          NaN     NaN
```

Running the above code gives:

```
    USERID    Year
0       fb  2021.0
1       fb  2022.0
4  twitter  2022.0
```

Comment: This is not working when there are multiple userID with >= 3 weekly consecutive logins from different years

Comment: are you sure? Can you please provide more data in your question?

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to be working

Comment: I have updated the question with more data and different output.

Comment: For the updated data in my question, the code is not giving me correct output.